# Initialize parameters by enum type

Tags: java, enums

So I'm given a task in my assignment that goes as follows:

An AirCraft is a PublicTransportation that in addition has the following: class type (enumeration type that can be: Helicopter, Airline, Glider or Balloon), and maintenance type (enumeration type that can be: Weekly, Monthly, or Yearly).

We haven't really covered what enum is but I'm trying to learn about it. I know that they are a list of constants (static and final). I just don't know how to initialize enum parameters in my driver class.

```
public class Aircraft extends PublicTransportation
{

    private enum ClassType {HELICOPTER, AIRLINE, GLIDER, BALLOON}
    private enum MaintType {WEEKLY, MONTHLY, YEARLY}

    private ClassType cType;
    private MaintType mType;

    public Aircraft()
    {
        super();
        cType = null;
        mType = null;
    }

    public Aircraft(double ticketPrice, int numOfStops, ClassType cType, MaintType mType)
    {
        super(ticketPrice, numOfStops);
        this.cType = cType;
        this.mType = mType;     
    }

    public Aircraft(Aircraft anAircraft)
    {
        super(anAircraft.getTicketPrice(), anAircraft.getNumOfStops());
        this.cType = anAircraft.cType;
        this.mType = anAircraft.mType;
    }
}
```

And here is a piece of my driver class:

```
package Driver;
import CityBus.CityBus;
import CityBus.Metro;
import CityBus.Tram;
import Ferry.Ferry;
import Aircraft.Aircraft;
import Aircraft.Aircraft;
import PublicTransportation.PublicTransportation;

public class Driver 
{



    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

        Aircraft ac1 = new Aircraft(1,2, GLIDER, Aircraft.GLIDER);
```

How do you initialize an enum type?

Comment: You can't, because the enums are declared private in the Aircraft class. So only Aircraft can access them. Move them outside of the class, in their own Java source file, just like you would do with a regular top-level class, and use ClassType.HELICOPTER.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the declarations to

```
public static enum ClassType {HELICOPTER, AIRLINE, GLIDER, BALLOON}
public static enum MaintType {WEEKLY, MONTHLY, YEARLY}
```

and in your driver class

```
Aircraft ac1 = new Aircraft(1,2, Aircraft.ClassType.GLIDER, Aircraft.MaintType.WEEKLY);
```

I fixed the problem in the invocation of the `Aircraft` constructor by guessing that gliders get maintenance weekly :-)

If you don't want to type the fully qualified enum constants you can `import static` at the top of the file:

```
import static Aircraft.ClassType.*;
import static Aircraft.MaintType.*;
```

and then use the enum constants without qualification.  However, as @LewBloch points out in a comment, static imports can reduce code readability. I myself am somewhat ambivalent about their use.  In specific circumstances, with sufficient documentation/warning in the code, they can be useful.  I generally avoid them.  I included them just for completeness, not as an endorsement.

Comment: Sometimes it's good to statically important enum constants, but more often the code is clearer if you import the class. `<class>.<constant>` is not a fully-qualified name. `<package>.<class>.<constant>` is a fully-qualified name.

Comment: Yes, I am ambivalent about static imports.  I will add your comment to the post.